# How to implement in-app-Billing in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, google-play-services, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement in-app-Billing in libgdx game. Does someone have a working example? There is some explanation on *developer.android* but it's not helpful for libgdx.

Comment: [Cross platform IAP Libgdx](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few standard extensions on the wiki - check out https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/gdx-pay